# Floating divs left/right without separating them on large window

Tags: html, css, css-float

The following example shows floating div on the left and right with two different container widths.

For large container (or large window), the divs floating left stick to the left border, and the div floating right stick to the right.

Is there a way to force the divs to stick together (horizontally centered in the container) when the container is large? Note that fixing the width of the container or that of any div is not an option.

Ideally, I would like to avoid javascript.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.inner1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #aff;
}
.inner2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffa;
}
.inner3 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #faf;
}
```

```html
First example with wide container<br />
<div class="container" style="width:400px">
  <div class="inner1"><---------- First</div>
  <div class="inner2">Second
    <br />--------
    <br />------</div>
  <div class="inner3">Third ----------</div>
</div>
<br />
Second example with small container<br />
<div class="container" style="width:100px">
  <div class="inner1"><---------- First</div>
  <div class="inner2">Second
    <br />--------
    <br />------</div>
  <div class="inner3">Third ----------</div>
</div>
```

EDIT : 
The reason why I'm using floats is to prevent the default ordering of divs. When non-floating, they are ordered either left-to-right or top-to-bottom, or both. This ordering prevents, sometime, useful space to be filled. For example, imagine div1 wide but not tall, and div2 thin and tall. If the screen is large enough, div2 will be to the right of div1. There will be a lot of space left below div1 and to the left of div2. I want to put div3 in that space. But because of the ordering, div3 will go to the right or below div2.

To resolve this problem, I used floating divs, but it created the other problem I stated initially: floating left/right makes divs separate on large screens.

If the problem can be solved without floats, it would be best.

Comment: Why do you have to avoid the use of javascript?

Answer (score 0):

i cant comment yet, since im pretty new. 
so i will just talk
if i understand the question right, You
might be looking for the

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

I hope thats what you where looking for.

Comment: I am not looking for vertical alignment. Only horizontal, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ywybk2n0/)? Just remove float from `.inner3`.

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.inner1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #aff;
}
.inner2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffa;
}
.inner3 {
  background-color: #faf;
}
```

---

```
First example with wide container<br />
<div class="container" style="width:400px">
  <div class="inner1"><---------- First</div>
  <div class="inner2">Second
    <br />--------
    <br />------</div>
  <div class="inner3">Third ----------</div>
</div>
<br />
Second example with small container<br />
<div class="container" style="width:100px">
  <div class="inner1"><---------- First</div>
  <div class="inner2">Second
    <br />--------
    <br />------</div>
  <div class="inner3">Third ----------</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not prevent inner2 and inner3 from separating I believe. But thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 `@media` query. Just float the divs on screen with 400px width and above.

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.inner1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #aff;
}
.inner2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffa;
}
.inner3 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #faf;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .inner1 {
    float: left;
  }
  .inner2 {
    float: left;
  }
  .inner3 {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

The container will centered on the screen width >= 400px. And the inner divs will float to the left. By default, the inner1, inner2, and inner3 will be floated to the left, right, and left respectively.

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dart67cn)

Comment: This is not a good solution because 400px is just an example. I don't want that to happen at a given size. All inner divs could have any size.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in this case remove `display: inline-block;` from `.container` and add `overflow: hidden;` here and into `.inner3` :

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner1 {
  float: left;
  background-color: #aff;
}
.inner2 {
  float: right;
  background-color: #ffa;
}
.inner3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #faf;
  float: left;
}
```

**EDIT** jsfiddle:
[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/6Ld8gc8w/3/)

Comment: With your solution, the inner1 and inner2 are still separated when extending the container width. Is that right?

Comment: @fffred, with `float` you haven't different solutions, because it changes position other elements in DOM. in this case you can use `@media` with other styles for different screens

Comment: But what media size should I use if I don't already know the size of my divs?   All divs have sizes depending on their content.

Comment: OK for masonry. But I'll still prefer a pure CSS solution.